# Type narrowing in react-query

Tags: react-query

Does **Type Narrowing** work like it used to?

Why `coffeesQuery.data` has the type `string[] | undefined` after all the checks and not `string[]`

*First image contains code without the error popup for clarity.*[image: react-query/typescript code][image: react-query/typescript error]

*ps*: I am getting the same typescript error even if i use `coffeesQuery.isSuccess` or `coffeesQuery.status === 'success'`

**Update**:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "react-query": "^2.26.4",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "4.6.3"
  }
}
```

**The error exists because I am using v2 of react-query. Updated to v3 and all work fine.**

Comment: I believe the issue is due to the fetchCoffees function not handling any kind of error? If that axios call fails it would return undefined not a string[]. Or similarly, there is an issue with the type that useQuery returns, potentially as undefined if no data as found instead of an empty list.

Comment: but that's what the isError and isLoading checks are for - they narrow the type...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have reproduced your screenshot in codesandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/type-narrowing-4dv3ci

the state machine has four states: idle, loading, error, success. If you check for the first three, what remains is success, so `data` should be narrowed correctly to your type, and it also does show that in my example.

Please show your own codesandbox or TypeScript playground reproduction where this doesn't work.

side note: the idle states will be removed in v4.